# `the` or no article?

Tags: definite-article, abstract-nouns

"dialogue" is an abstract thing. So, should we say

"End of the dialogue."

Or

"End of dialogue."

?

Comment: In what context? In a complete sentence you need an article (_This is the end of the dialogue_), but if it's just a note indicating that the dialogue is over, you can leave it out.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for an explanation.

Comment: @user2925716 "Abstract" or "concrete" does not really make a difference for the use of articles, by the way.  A *dream* is certainly abstract, but you can say "a dream" or "the dream".  The difference that you're looking for is more about *general* vs. *specific*, like "*Government* (in general) is the system that..." vs. "*The government* (of this country) has announced that..."

Comment: @stangdon But dreams are countable. You can't do: Dream is over.

Comment: Both options are grammatically correct, but they have slightly different meanings.
Using the definite article "the" implies that there is a specific dialogue that is being referred to, and it has come to an end. 
Leaving out the article and saying "End of dialogue" is more general, and implies the ending of any dialogue in a broader sense. 
So, it depends on the context of what you are trying to convey.